# How am I misusing the null-coalescing operator? Is this evaluating "null" correctly? I want it to show as 'Unknown' if it is null

Tags: postgresql

this is my code

I want the age column to display as Unknown if it is NULL. However, it is not accepting my COALESCE part  after the DATE_PART subtraction

SELECT

COALESCE(DATE_PART('year', death::date) - DATE_PART('year', birth::date), 'Unknown') AS age,

FROM emperors
ORDER BY name ASC

DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type double precision: "Unknown"
LINE 5: ...', death::date) - DATE_PART('year', birth::date), 'Unknown')...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every member of the `COALESCE` function must be of the same data type.
You have mixed `double precision` type and `text` type. Solution :

```
SELECT
COALESCE((DATE_PART('year', death::date) - DATE_PART('year', birth::date)) :: text, 'Unknown') AS age
FROM emperors ORDER BY name ASC
```